# Scala Play framework-2.1.1 AsyncResult: Handling multiple futures

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to generate various code snippets based on user posted data, so those snippet generation can be parallel, I am trying to use futures for each and snippet generation and combine them and send AsyncResult, here is the code

```
val p = for {
  pr <- Future { ProviderGenerator.generate(content) }
  c <- Future { ModelGenerator.generate(content) }
} yield(pr, c)

Async {
  if (p.isCompleted)
    println("Futures completed")
  p.onSuccess({
    case (pr: ActionResult, c: ActionResult) => {
      response.add(pr)
      response.add(c)
      Ok(Json.toJson(response))
    }
  })
  p onFailure {
    case _ => println("It failed")
  }
  p.map {
    case (pr: ActionResult, c: ActionResult) => {
      println("I am in case")
      response.add(pr)
      response.add(c)
      Ok(Json.toJson(response))
    }
    case _ => {
      println("I am in else case")
      Ok(Json.toJson(response))
    }
  }
}
```

This is never sending result to user, where as if I use single future in it, I am getting response. How do I handle such multiple futures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious problem - try adding a `p onFailure { case e: Throwable => Logger.error("failed", e) }` perhaps and see if it shows one future is not completing.

Comment: Yes failure code snippet is there in my code, but to shorten the requirement I have not added it here. Anyhow I edited my question to show whatever I have done. Neither of the cases are getting executed. I am not able to see any of the prints

Comment: if one of the generate() didn't complete (just blocked indefinitely) then none of those prints would be reached ... you might add more prints earlier on to try to find exactly what gets stuck.

Comment: Due to some unknown reason second future is not getting invoked. That is the generator function is not getting invoked. Changed the way invoking generator, then it started working.

Comment: The pont you mentioned helped me to identify the problem. Thank you. My actual doubt I have is, is this correct way to handle multiple parallel events or is there better way to handle these kind of cases?

Comment: The for() syntax here will expand to something like `Future { ProviderGenerator.generate() } flatMap { _ => Future { ModelGenerator.generate() } }` I believe... (plus building the tuple)... so the second future doesn't kick off until the first is completed successfully -- this is often useful to cause a series of futures to execute sequentially, but here perhaps it isn't what you wanted.  You could kick off and save both intermediate futures first, like `val prFuture = Future { }` and then use the for just to extract `for { pr <- prFuture; c <- cFuture } yield (pr, c)` perhaps.